# Show that the quotient group $T/N$ is abelian

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

let $T= \begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&d\end{bmatrix}, a, b, d \in \mathbb{R}, ad \neq 0$

And let $N = \begin{bmatrix}1&b\\0&1\end{bmatrix}, b\in \mathbb{R}$

I showed that N is a normal subgroup of T

Now I have to show that the quptient group $\dfrac{T}{N}$ is an abelian group (I am not sure what that quotient group represents).

I would need a hint to solve this problem

Answer (score 4):

Define a map $\phi:T\to\mathbb{R}^{\times}\times\mathbb{R}^{\times}$ by
$$ \phi\Big(\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&d\end{bmatrix}\Big)=(a,d) $$
This is a homomorphism because if $t_j=\begin{bmatrix}a_j&b_j\\0&d_j\end{bmatrix}\in T$, $j=1,2$, then
$$ \begin{bmatrix}a_1&b_1\\0&d_1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a_2&b_2\\0&d_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}a_1a_2&a_1b_2+b_1d_2\\0&d_1d_2\end{bmatrix}$$
hence $\phi(t_1t_2)=(a_1a_2,d_1d_2)=(a_1,d_1)(a_2,d_2)=\phi(t_1)\phi(t_2)$.

Since $\mathbb{R}^{\times}\times\mathbb{R}^{\times}$ is an abelian group, all that's left to do is to show that $\phi$ is surjective, and that the kernel is $N$, then use the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: Lesson: when dealing with quotient groups, use FIT. Quotient groups are messy and cumbersome to deal with, so you can save much time and energy by finding something else you are familiar with, that the quotient group is isomorphic to by... FIT. No need to deal with cosets and representative elements, the homomorphism cleans all that up for you.

Comment: @silvascientist It really should be a mantra: quotient groups are nothing but homomorphic images, and the latter are often much easier to work with.

Answer (score 4):

**Lemma.** Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of a group $G$. Then $G/H$ is abelian if and only if $aba^{-1}b^{-1}\in H$ whenever $a,b\in G$.

A quick proof can be found [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Abelian_Quotient_Group).

Now, to apply the lemma to our situation, let
\begin{align*}
A &=
\left[\begin{array}{rr}
a & b \\
0 & c
\end{array}\right] &
B &=
\left[\begin{array}{rr}
w & x \\
0 & y
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}
be elements of $T$.

Then
$$
ABA^{-1}B^{-1}=
\left[\begin{array}{rr}
1 & -\frac{\frac{b w}{c} - \frac{a x + b y}{c}}{y} - \frac{x}{y} \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right]
$$
so $ABA^{-1}B^{-1}\in T$. The lemma then implies that $G/H$ is abelian.