# Is this reasoning correct to prove that a factor group is abelian?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

**Given:**
$T$ is group of nonsingular $2\times2$ UTM with entries in $\mathbb{R}$. $U$ consists of matrices of the form $$\begin{pmatrix}1 & x\\ 0& 1\end{pmatrix}$$.

**To prove:**
$T/U$ is abelian.

I am learning this subject on my own so I just wanted to confirm if my reasoning is correct. I found similar question here but answers provided are along a different tangent. Here is my reasoning.
$T/U$ consists of equivalence classes of group $T$. Say an arbitrary element in T given by $\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\0 & c\end{bmatrix}$ generates class $\begin{bmatrix}a & a\lambda+b\\0&c\end{bmatrix}$. Hence, $a_{1,2}$ in this class is basically all possible linear combinations of $a,b$ for given $a,b,c$.
Say two different elements (which are sets of elements of original group) can be represented by $\begin{bmatrix}a&a\lambda+b\\0&c\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}d&d\mu+e\\0&f\end{bmatrix}$ for given $a,b,c,d,e,f$.

Hence, if we are able to prove that the class generated by  $\begin{bmatrix}a&a\lambda+b\\0&c\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}d&d\mu+e\\0&f\end{bmatrix}$ is the same as class generated by $\begin{bmatrix}d&d\mu+e\\0&f\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a&a\lambda+b\\0&c\end{bmatrix}$ , we will have proved that $T/U$ is abelian.

$\begin{equation}\begin{bmatrix}a&a\lambda+b\\0&c\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}d&d\mu+e\\0&f\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}ad&ad\mu+ae+af\lambda+bf\\0&cf\end{bmatrix}\end{equation}$

$\begin{bmatrix}d&d\mu'+e\\0&f\end{bmatrix}\begin{equation}\begin{bmatrix}a&a\lambda'+b\\0&c\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}ad&ad\lambda'+bd+cd\mu'+ce\\0&cf\end{bmatrix}\end{equation}$.

This is essentially now a problem of linear algebra. We have to check that $a_{1,2}$ "spans" the same $1-D$ space for given $a, b, c, d, e,f$ which is easily proved.

Is this correct? There are several other approaches pointed here but I just want to know if this reasoning is correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can also compare with the same post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2024488/show-that-t-u-is-abelian?rq=1) to check it.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks. Didn't see this one.